# How to remove prepended line of whitepace wordpress plugin

Tags: php, string, wordpress, plugins, whitespace

Good day. I am pulling my hair out with this probably silly problem. i have started writing a new plugin ( wordpress ) . all i have written is the following

```
 <?php 
 /*
 Plugin Name: Undercon Page Pro
 Plugin URI:#
 Description: Responsive Fullscreen Underconstruction page.
 Version: 0.1
 Author: Nyasha Dhliwayo
 Author URI: #
 License: GPLv2 / Commercial
 */

 //First things first, in the event of direct entry attempt

 // Version 


 $custom_registered_post_returned = "'saver','book'";
 echo $custom_registered_post_returned ;
 exit;
```

When i run the code just to see if it will echo the strings correctly i find that if i open view page source it has somehow created an extra line of whitespace before the actual string comes out.
I have tried using wp_strip_all_tags function but it does not work. Does anyone know how to remove this whitespace.
Please help

Comment: When I run your code exactly as you've got it there, I see no extra white space in either IE or Chrome.

Comment: im runnig wordpress locally, xampp.

Comment: i get the rpoblem in chrome and firefox

Comment: Okay, well, then you need to look somewhere else because it's not your code doing it.

Comment: Ok thanks, when i run the code as just a php file i get no white space as well ? pulling my hair out here. Any suggestions Mr Lance

Comment: No, sorry.  I don't know Wordpress.  I looked at your question because of the [php] tag.  Wish I could be of more help but I'm sure you'll get a Wordpress expert here soon enough.  Good luck.

Comment: I'm using wamp locally but I couldn't see white space on chrome/firefox either. When I do var_dump() on  `$custom_registered_post_returned` I get `string ''saver','book'' (length=14)`. No spaces here

Comment: sounds pretty likely that it's code running before what you've quoted that is causing this problem. Nothing you've written should cause this. Make sure there's no blank line above that `<?php` tag though of course ;)